# How to import an existing c++ project to XCode8?

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11, xcode8

I have a c++ project that I'd like to import to XCode8 for the sole purpose of having access to a better debugger.

Does anyone know how to do the import?

Answer (score 2):

Use CMake to generate an Xcode project:

`cmake -GXcode .`

Comment: Is that the only way? I'm using a simple Makefile right now, and am pretty happy with it

Comment: I see no other way. But CMake can generate Makefiles too.

Comment: Premake is a lightweight and open source alternative to CMake. You should check it out, it's clearly easier